# How can I change UITableViewCell background color with a switch?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm making a dark mode switch, and I'm only missing the cells to change their color to black when I turn it on, how can this be done? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tryed so far?

Comment: We'd need to see more code but you can probably just reload the data of your table with a call to `reloadData()`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below.

`tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red`

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this method to your class and attach UISwitch value change to this action:

```
@IBAction func changeColorAction(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    let visibleCells: [UITableViewCell] = tableView.visibleCells

    for cell in visibleCells {
        if sender.isOn {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        }else {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
    }
}
```

then, implement this in your tableView delegate method:

```
internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath)

    if switch.isOn {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    }else {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Still, these don't work, if you want I can send my code.